# How do I place my function to the 3rd column of a matrix in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, function, fortran, gfortran

I am a newbie at Fortran so I need your help with something.
I am trying to see the result of the function in column 3 but can't compile whatever I did.
I am receiving an error:

```
48 |         datatable(lowrange:highrange,3) = myfunc(datatable(i,1), datatable(i,2))
|        

 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

And here is my text:

```
program main_homework
    use type_real
    implicit none
    real(kind=rk), parameter :: year=1995, day=28, month=12
    real(kind=rk), dimension (:,:), allocatable :: datatable
    integer :: i, j
    integer :: fileid, lowrange, highrange
    real(kind=rk) :: myfunc
    real(kind=rk) :: dx, dy
    real(kind=rk) :: x,y
    real(kind=rk), dimension(:), allocatable :: ytemp
    integer :: no_1Dnodes, no_nodes

    no_nodes = year/10.0

    no_1Dnodes = int(sqrt(no_nodes*1.0_rk)) + 1


    dx = day/(no_1Dnodes - 1)
    dy = month/(no_1Dnodes - 1)



    allocate(datatable(no_1Dnodes**2, 3))
    allocate(ytemp(no_1Dnodes))

    do i=1, ubound(ytemp,1)
        ytemp(i) = (i-1)*dy
    end do


    do i=1, no_1Dnodes
        lowrange = 1 + no_1Dnodes*(i-1)
        highrange = no_1Dnodes*i
        datatable(lowrange:highrange, 1) = (i-1)*dx
        datatable(lowrange:highrange, 2) = ytemp
        datatable(i,1) = x
        datatable(i,2) = y

    end do

    do i=1, no_1Dnodes
       myfunc = x**3 * cos(y) + y**3 * sin(x)
       datatable(lowrange:highrange,3)=myfunc
    end do

    do i=1, ubound(datatable,1)
       48 datatable(i,3) = myfunc(datatable(i,1), datatable(i,2))
    end do
    print *, datatable
    open(newunit=fileid, file="grid_data.csv", status="replace", action="write")


    do i=1, ubound(datatable,1)
        write(fileid, *) datatable(i,:)
    end do
    close(fileid)


end program main_homework
```

I tried a couple alternatives to see the function in Excel but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you intend `myfunc` to be a scalar, an array or a function? It has to be exactly one of them, but you aren't consistent in what you tell the compiler it is.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. In your title you write that you want to put a functuon into an array. In Fortran that makes no sense. You can place a result into an array, but not a function itself. For advanced programmers there are also function pointers which can appear in an array, but let's keep them away.